# SVG getAttribute/setAttribute simply adding to coordinates instead of "setting"?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    onload="startup(evt)">
<script>
function startup(evt){
    svgDoc=evt.target.ownerDocument;
    setInterval(function(){step("zero");},1000);
    setInterval(function(){follow("zero","one");},950);
}

function step(e,follower){
    e=svgDoc.getElementById(e);
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
    var rand2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
    var move = 10;
    var y = +(e.getAttribute("y"));
    var x = +(e.getAttribute("x"));
    if(rand == 1){  
        if(rand2 == 1){
        e.setAttribute("y",y + move);
        } else {
        e.setAttribute("y",y - move);
        }
    } else {
    if(rand2 == 1){
        e.setAttribute("x",x + move);
        } else {
        e.setAttribute("x",x - move);
        }
    }
}
function follow(leader, follower){
    follower = svgDoc.getElementById(follower);
    leader = svgDoc.getElementById(leader);

    var leaderY = leader.getAttribute("y");
    var leaderX = leader.getAttribute("x");

    follower.setAttribute("y", leaderY);
    follower.setAttribute("x", leaderX);
}

</script>   
<defs>
    <text id="zero">0</text>
    <text id="one">1</text>
</defs>
<use x="50" y="50" xlink:href="#zero"/>
<use x="10" y="10" xlink:href="#one"/>
</svg>
```

Just doing some random exercises to build my logic and practice scripting.

Basically, I mean for the "one" to follow the "zero". The zero moves randomly, and it's position is put into memory /stored a tiny bit (50ms) before it is suppose to move. The one is then meant to be set to this position. Instead, I just get the "One" following the movement pattern of the "Zero", instead of its previous position. I'm curious to why this is, because I am not doing any sort of actual addition to the "one" svg element.

Comment: Is using javascript an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly zero and one have no attributes to begin with so getAttribute will return null. Changing your markup to this will fix it

```
<defs>
    <text id="zero" x="0" y="0">0</text>
    <text id="one" x="0" y="0">1</text>
</defs>
```

Secondly getAttribute returns a string so you need to use parseFloat to get a number out of it e.g.

```
var y = parseFloat(e.getAttribute("y"));
var x = parseFloat(e.getAttribute("x"));
```

Making these two changes seems to make it do what you want

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea that the attributes would be null. I suppose using set attribute at one point before the SetIntervals will also solve the issue of being null.

Additionally, I think I can use    var x = +(e.getAttribute("x")); to parse it into a numeric, as I do in the step() function.  

Thanks again.