# How to get Inner tags in <g> tags in svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am working with **SVG** `<g>` tags using JavaScript. I need get the inner tags (eg: `rect`, `path`, etc)  in each of the `<g>` tags.

This is what I used to get a particular tag.

```
var stess = selectedElement.getElementsByTagName('rect');
console.log(stess);
```

But I have dynamic tags as well. how should I retrieve the values of the inner tags? More so, how could I change the width of these inner tags?

Here is the code that I tried:

```
$('.test').change(function() {
            console.log(selectedElement.children()); // Results Error
}
```

I end up logging `<g id="xxx" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1"><rect></g>`. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Grabbing a Child** (er, can I write that?)

First, to grab all of the children of a `<g>` tag, you could use the `childNodes` attribute ([big example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201782/accessing-the-svg-data-through-javascript)):

```
var allGs = document.getElementsByTagName('g');
var firstG = allGs[0];
var firstChild = firstG.childNodes[0];
```

Then you could grab each child's bounding box to grab the width/height. I'd use the `getBBox` method ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702952/how-to-get-width-of-svgg-element)):

```
var boundingBox= firstChild.getBBox();
var width = boundingBox.width
```

For more on bounding boxes, check out the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html#BoundingBox).

Here's [an example **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn49e/1/) showing how to get the attribute from a child.

---

**Multiple Children**

And here's another example [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A9U38/4/) that grabs the widths of all the children of each `<g>` tag -- or see the relevant code below:

```
var allGs = document.getElementsByTagName('g');

for (var i=0; i<allGs.length; i++) {
 var gElem = allGs[i];
 var children = gElem.children;

 // `children` is an array of the form [child, child, ...].

 for (var j=0; j < children.length; j++){
  var child = children[j];   
  var box = child.getBBox();
  var width = box.width;

  //... Now do whatever you wanted to do with the width.

 }
}
```

*Note: `element.childNodes` will collect unwanted whitespace between children elements; `element.children` only selects the children ([Docs](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-children)). Thanks, [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109374/erik-dahlstr%C3%B6m)!*

---

**Setting Attributes**

A quick note that if all you want to do is change the width, you don't need to grab the bound box; you can just use the `setAttribute` method ([source](http://www.unet.univie.ac.at/~a9900479/svg4tom/svg4tom1.html)). For example, if you wanted to set the width of the first child to 100px:

```
//A condensed version of the "firstChild" retrieval from before:
var firstChild = document.getElementsByTagName('g')[0].childNodes[0];
var newWidth = 100;
firstChild.setAttribute("width", newWidth)
```

[Example **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Us47r/1/)

---

**Retrieving Attributes**

Regarding retrieving other "values" -- that depends on what you mean. If you want an *attribute*, then you could just use the `getAttribute` method ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)) of each child instead of grabbing the BBox's width ([SO post with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784821/svg-getattribute-setattribute-simply-adding-to-coordinates-instead-of-setting)). That is done in a similar way to how we *sets* an attribute in the code snippet above:

```
//A condensed version of the "firstChild" retrieval from before:
var firstChild = document.getElementsByTagName('g')[0].childNodes[0];
var value = firstChild.getAttribute("src")
// ... Now do what you will with that value.
```

[Example **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ks7d/1/)

Comment: For the multiple children case if you only want Elements, an option is to use `Element.children` instead of `Element.childNodes`, see http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-children.

Comment: Ahh, good to know, @ErikDahlström! Thanks. Just updated the answer to include that knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS child selectors in jQuery to get the required elements.

```
var rects = $('g > rect');
var circles = $('g > rect');
var paths = $('g > rect');
```

This will select the dynamic elements also which exits at the time of execution of this statement.

For example to change all rect widths.

```
$('g > rect').each(function(){
  $(this).attr("width","10");
  console.log($(this));
});
```

You can say,

```
for each(var childElement in selectedElement.childNodes)
{
    console.log(childElement)
}
```

This will give you individual child elements from the array.

Comment: Hi @sadiq.ali..How to get dynamic value.? I have path, circle and so many also..so provide brief explanation...

Comment: I need to get child tags from <g> tags. I try to get "console.log(selectedElement.childNodes);" but i`ll results rect array.I need to pass rect tags into other function so i need to get inner tag from <g> tags

Comment: This question doesn't have a jQuery tag.

Comment: Try querySelector or querySelectorAll method.

Comment: But the question has jQuery snippet.

Comment: jQuery doesn't always play nicely with SVGs -- best to avoid as many issues as we can. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793312/how-to-use-jquery-in-svg-scalable-vector-graphics)